# Add new columns in header and contents in csv file

Tags: php, csv

I want to add to new columns to my existing csv file using php.
Therefore I currently have the following code, but that one use column separator `,` and my existing csv use `;` as column separator.

So how can I extend my current code and change the column separator from `,` to `;`?

```
<?php
$inFile = fopen('test.csv','r');
$outFile = fopen('output.csv','w');

$line = fgetcsv($inFile);
while ($line !== false) {
        $line[] = 'third column';
        $line[] = 'fourth column';
        fputcsv($outFile, $line);
        $line = fgetcsv($inFile);
}
fclose($inFile);
fclose($outFile);
```

Comment: Try with this: fputcsv($outFile, $line, ';');

Comment: You can specify column separator for for `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv`.

Comment: You should really go read the manual for the functions you are using on your own before asking stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code provided above, please change:

```
fputcsv($outFile, $line);
```

to

```
fputcsv($outFile, $line, ';'); // default delimiter is "," and ";" provided
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

So, your final code will look like:

```
<?php
$inFile = fopen('test.csv','r');
$outFile = fopen('output.csv','w');

$line = fgetcsv($inFile);
while ($line !== false) {
        $line[] = 'third column';
        $line[] = 'fourth column';
        fputcsv($outFile, $line, ';');
        $line = fgetcsv($inFile);
}
fclose($inFile);
fclose($outFile);
```